# Using shell in Makefile to find Ubuntu Version

Tags: shell, ubuntu, awk, makefile

I'm trying make Ubuntu version specific distros of my tool so I want to get the os name and version. I have the following code:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    OS_POD+=win
else
    UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
    ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
            OS_VERS := $(shell lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null | grep Description | awk '{ print $2 "-" $3 }')
            OS_POD=./dist/linux/$(OS_VERS)
    endif
    ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Darwin)
            OS_POD=./dist/mac
    endif
endif
```

I use the shell one-liner:

```
lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null | grep Description | awk '{ print $2 "-" $3 }'
```

Which properly returns `Ubuntu-12.04.2` outside of the Makefile, but inside it it returns nothing. That is, the OS_VERS variable is just `-`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Makefile, `$` is special. Use `$$` where you want the shell to find a dollar.

```
OS_VERS := $(shell lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null | grep Description | awk '{ print $$2 "-" $$3 }')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but sadly this doesn't work. The output is `2-` now instead.

Comment: Sorry I was being stupid and editing the file on my local machine, thinking I was editing it on the linux box #facepalm...you were right :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `$` inside your command.

```
OS_VERS:=$(shell lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null | grep Description | awk '{ print $$2 "-" $$3 }')
```

The following sample Makefile prints correctly so it may be a different part of your Makefile.

```
print: 
    @echo $(OS_VERS)

OS_VERS:=$(shell lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null | grep Description | awk '{ print $$2 "-" $$3 }')
```

Answer (score 0):

`OS_VERS := $(shell cat /etc/os-release | grep ^NAME | cut -d'=' -f2 | sed 's/\"//gI')`

Comment: What's the benefit of this syntax over the previous answers?